# How do I pass Great Little War Game Mission 15? ("Holiday")?

Tags: great-little-war-game

In Android game "Great Little War Game", how do I pass Level 15 mission ("Holiday")? I can hold out for many turns, but in the end the heavier units overwhelm me - snipers, tanks and even commandos, in waves of 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of specifics of game mechanics that make this a fairly easy (if somewhat tedious) mission to complete. They are as follows:

1. Enemy landing craft can **only** land reinforcements on un-occupied beach "squares"

   - **Corollary 1**: If every spot on the beach is occupied by your units, enemy cannot land reinforcements on that beach at all.
   - **Corollary 2**: If only 1 spot on the beach is unoccupied, only one enemy reinforcement can be landed on that beach this turn, letting you easily overwhelm it.
2. Enemy reinforcements do not attack in the turn when they land.

   This means that you can pick and choose which units start the attack on reinforcements.
3. Each of the starting enemy reinforcements have weaknesses:

   - **Grunt**: Firing radius of 2 (can be targeted by units on the hills from 3 steps away without retaliatory fire), and weak (can be killed by 2 shots from regular grunt units, or 1 shot from Sniper or even promoted Grunt).

     **Attack tactics against grunt**: Fire one shot at it from a unit on the hill 3 steps away. This takes down 75% of its power. If you run out of hill-3-steps-away units to do that to fresh grunts, second priority is to shoot fresh grunts with your fresh grunts (they are taken down to 25% power, and return fire only takes off 15% of your grunt's power). Third priority - sometimes - is finishing off near-dead grunts (see point #4).
   - **Sniper**: Firing radius of 2-3 (can be targeted by units - even grunts - 1 step away without retaliation) and not super-strong (can be killed by 2 grunt shots).
   - **Recon tank**: Weak fire against infantry (only takes off ~15-20% off grunt's health in 1 shot); and weak against Bazooka unit (can be killed with 2 hits).
4. Promotion heals the unit AND amps up its power (promoted grunt can kill regular grunt in 1 shot).

### ----

---

So, overall strategy for that mission is:

- Produce only grunts, as fast as you can (until ~wave 10 or so, when first Recon Tanks are landed and you need Bazooka units).
- In the initial waves, use the anti-Grunt tactics as described above, to kill off all landed grunts

  - If possible, concentrate a couple of designated grunt units to do all the final kills so they get promoted (it takes 3 kills for promotion). This is helpful in mid-game but non-essential to the grand strategy.
  - At the start, place as many of your grunts (especially non-promoted ones) as you can on the hills that overlook the landing beach strips from the distance of 3. This helps greately in anti-grunt tactics - the hill units shoot at 3-away new grunts, letting beach units kill the weakened grunt with second shot.

  There is one hill with 3+1 spots near your barracks, that can hit nearby beach and nearest area of right side beach; a big hill all the way to the right covering the rest of right side beach; and small hill all the way on the left for left side beach.
- Past wave 5-8, when you produce enough grunts - start filling the beaches!

  I personally first filled the top left beach (smallest one) first. Then the right-most beach, which is the biggest, from the middle to the ends (because the ends are covered by the hills and are better killing ground). Then the one near your barracks, since it's easiest to attack due to short distance from the barracks.

  If you don't have enough grunts, leave 1 or 2 empty spots on a beach - a single landed unit there is easy to overwhelm in earlier turns. Then as you produce more grunts, fill the holes.
- Around wave 8 or 10, you should have 2 beaches filled in.
- Around wave ~7, enemy reinforcements start including snipers. They are trivial to kill at that time, with grunts only - move a grunt 1 square away from the sniper for the first shot (that takes off 50% of the sniper, with no retaliatory shot) and then use a second grunt to deliver the killing second shot for the other 50%.
- Around wave ~10? the reinforcements start including recon tanks. Make sure you have a couple Bazooka units by then, to take out the tanks. 2 Bazooka shots per recon tank does it, and they are weak against infantry and thus can't cause much damage even if not killed upon landing.
- By wave 10 or 12, you should have enough grunts produced to occupy 100% of spots on ALL the beaches. At that point, you won -from then on, the enemy cannot land ANY units at all; so even if they start sending more powerful ones (Artillery/commando), they can't land. Ever.